# Record / Upload a fixed length video with progress bar using HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am making a small project in HTML & Java-script, where a user can record a video and upload it to the server.

However, I can't figure out how to show a progress bar as the user starts recording. The video should either be stopped by user once they are done recording, or if it reaches a specific time limit set by me.

Once, the user has finished recording, they can either re-record the video or upload it on the server.

Can someone please help me out on this ?  I am complete a beginner in this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to an article where you can find this information in great detail. Scroll down to the part where it says "Tracking Progress".

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/drag-drop-file-uploader-vanilla-js/